# Парсер товаров ИКЕА

Tags: php, парсер

Хочу написать парсер товаров ИКЕА. могу вытащить все товары, но дело в том, что они различаются по цвету размеру и другим параметрам, а вся эта информация в одном окне. Помогите вытащить ее. http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/S39902937/

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
        $url = "http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/allproducts/";
        $html = file_get_html($url);
        $linkCat = $html->find('.textContainer a');
foreach($linkCat as $num => $cat) {
            $urlCat = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251","http://ikea.com".$linkCat[$num]->href);
            $htmlCat = file_get_html($urlCat);
            $linkGood = $htmlCat->find('.productLink');
            foreach($linkGood as $num => $good) {
                $urlGood = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251","http://ikea.com".$linkGood[$num]->href);
                echo $urlGood."<br>";
            }
```

Вот что сделал. Парсит все товары. Но дело в том что нужно еще спарсить товары которые отличаются по цвету и размерам, а ссылки на них нужно как то достать со страницы описания самого товара. Не знаю как(

Comment: PhantomJS может помочь

Comment: А что это? по подробнее расскажите

Comment: В двух словах - это фактически браузер, но он работает чисто на сервере с nodejs. Он парсит страницы как и обычный браузер: javascript, css, все. Но результат его работы можно отловить на сервере, и с ним что-то сделать. Мощная штука. Рекомендую почитать более подробно на сайте проекта.